# So I used fixubuntu as a privicy measure, what other precations should I take using Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: security, privacy

Yes, I just want a privacy preserving OS, I know it's not 100% possible but I'd like to get as close as I can.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Privacy Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/indicator-privacy/) lets you change some privacy related settings in Unity and remove some automatically collected data.

But it's likely far more important to configure your web browser to protect your privacy and to be careful where you enter what kind of information on the web.

Comment: Thanks. It's a typo and has to be `ppa:diesch/testing`. Fixed.

Comment: That's why I left the comment!  ;-)